# Cross-platform Desktop Notifications Module With Custom Action Support

Tags: python, module

Currently, I am working on a program that shows desktop notifications when a new post is made. However, I am working on making the notification clickable.

I am using winotify and then realized I will not get mac or linux support. I looked into notifypy, but it does not have custom action support. I started looking into desktop-notifier, but was wondering if there were any other recommendations. Would you recommend checking the platform type and sending the correct type of notification based on that? I would then use different types of modules.